# ym4r-gm custom map marker images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using the YM4R-GM Plugin to plot the locations of various businesses on my app.  I want to use a custom marker image in place of the standard red-pinking google maps marker.  Is this possible using this plugin? I am finding very sparse documentation on the internet.

Additionally, I would like to display a different marker on the map depending on what category the business falls under. There will be about 20 different images in all.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you have a look at my gem: gmaps4rails. It makes rhese things really easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use a custom marker image. Some time ago I developed an app with this feature, for rails 2. I found code [in this page](http://www.packtpub.com/article/find-closest-mashup-plugin-with-ruby-on-rails).

This is the code for generating the icon:

```
    @map.icon_global_init( GIcon.new(:image =>
             "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png",
                               :shadow => "http://www.google.com/
                                           mapfiles/shadow50.png",
                               :icon_size => GSize.new(32,32),
                               :shadow_size => GSize.new(37,32),
                               :icon_anchor => GPoint.new(9,32),
                               :info_window_anchor => GPoint.new(9,2),
                               :info_shadow_anchor =>
                                       GPoint.new(18,25)),
               "icon_source")
```

and this for creating marker:

```
source = GMarker.new([@location.lat, @location.lng],
             :icon => icon_source)
```

Where `icon_source` is the icon you created before and `source` is the location where you want to put the marker with the custom icon.

At the end just type: `@map.overlay_init(source)`

Finally you can find all google map markers [here](http://mabp.kiev.ua/2010/01/12/google-map-markers/).

If you have problems with this code, try in these pages, for rails 3: [rails 3 ym4r gm](http://www.postal-code.com/binarycode/2007/11/28/google-map-markers-in-ym4rgm/) and [here](http://eric.lubow.org/2009/ruby/rails/custom-google-maps-marker-with-ym4r_gm/)

I hope this helps you.